# Send link with variable using Zend_Mail

Tags: php, zend-framework, hyperlink, zend-mail, email-confirmation

I am triyng to send a email with a link when the user complete registration.
The link should have a variable $id with the id of the user.
I tried different things but my link always appear as
http://localhost/users-data/activate/.php?id=>

I am using Zend_Mail.
What I am trying to do, is for example: send to user id =1 a link http://localhost/users-data/activate1. For then I can take the last number of url, which should correspond to id, and set the status to this user in my activate script.

Could you show me what I doing wrong?

This is my registerAction

```
public function registerAction()
{
    // action body
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form    = new Application_Form_UsersData();

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        if ($form->isValid($request->getPost())) {
            $comment = new Application_Model_UsersData($form->getValues());
            $mapper  = new Application_Model_UsersDataMapper();
            $mapper->save($comment);

            // send email
            $id = $comment -> getId();
            $formValues = $this->_request->getParams();
            $mail = new Application_Model_Mail();
            $mail->sendActivationEmail($formValues['email'], $id,$formValues['name']);
            $this->_redirect('/users-data/regsuccess'); 

        }
    }

    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

This is my Application_Model_Mail

```
class Application_Model_Mail
{

    public function sendActivationEmail($email, $id,$name)
    {
        require_once('Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php');
        require_once 'Zend/Mail.php';


        $config = array('auth' => 'login',
                'username' => '*******@gmail.com',
                'password' => '******',
                'port'     => '587',
                'ssl' => 'tls');
        $tr = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com',$config);
        Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($tr);

        $mail = new Zend_Mail();

        $mail->setBodyText('Please click the following link to activate your account '
                  . '<a http://localhost/users-data/activate/.php?id='.$id.'>'.$id.'</a>')
                ->setFrom('admin@yourwebsite.com', 'Website Name Admin')
                ->addTo($email, $name)
                ->setSubject('Registration Success at Website Name')
                ->send($tr);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You go from `$request` to `$_request`. The latter is not defined anywhere, so its values are null.

Comment: Thank you for your answear. 
But looks like that at least the $email and $name are being setted, once that they appear in the email correctly. Anyway how I can define $_request ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$mail->setBodyHtml("Please click the following link to activate your".
"account<a href='http://localhost/users-data/activate.php?id=$id'>$id</a>")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Doing this way the link just does not appear in the email...

Answer (score -1):

The HTML link you create is incorrect:

```
'<a http://localhost/users-data/activate/.php?id='.$id.'>'
```

In HTML, a valid link is (note the `href` attribute):

```
<a href="http://...">...</a>
```

So your script should construct the link like this:

```
'<a href="http://localhost/users-data/activate/.php?id='.$id.'">'
```

Also, I suppose `http://localhost/users-data/activate/.php` is not what you want: your script has probably a name before the `php` extension.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
Even so  my email appear like this:

Please click the following link to activate your account <a href= http://localhost/users-data/activate/.php?id=></a> 

What I really want is just that the link, for example send to user id =1
a link http://localhost/users-data/activate1. 
For then I can take the last number of url, which should correspond to id, and set the status to this user in my activate script.